# Need information on Google Apps API

Tags: google-apps, google-admin-sdk

I am looking for information on Google Apps APIs.

1. Is it possible to terminate the user's active session using the Google Apps API? If yes, can you please provide me the details on how to do that.
2. I am using Directory API to access list of groups and update memberships of users: https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/groups. Can the same API be used to access and update the membership of collaborative groups also?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. No. This is an open Feature Request [here](https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=2849). Would be an awesome feature :)
2. Not sure what you mean by a 'collaborative group'. That being said, any admin-managed group (created in the Admin console) can have its membership modified by the Directory API.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding question 2, yes you can update group memberships of any groups in your Google Apps domain including Collaborative Inbox style groups. You would use the "Directory API: Group Members" endpoint, documented here:

> https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-group-members